# order products based on sort Id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a form which returns the products based on the sortId which I insert it in postman , every thing works , but orderby does not work for all of them .

```
    $products = Product::with('raffles')
    ->whereHas('categories',function($q2) use ($categoryId) {
        $q2->where('category_id', $categoryId);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($sortId) {
        //Default order
        if ($sortId == 1) {
            $query->orderBy('id');
        } 
        //Has raffle
        if ($sortId == 2) {
            $query->whereHas('raffles',function($q2) {
                $q2->where('active', 1);
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        } 
        //More sold tickets
        if ($sortId == 3) {

            $query->whereHas('raffles',function($q2) {
                $q2->where('active', 1)
                    ->orderBy('sold_ticket', 'asc');
            });
        } 
    })
   ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Isn't it `orderBy`? With a capital "B"?

Comment: last orderBy should be outside whereHas closure.

Comment: You say: *but orderby does not work for all of them.* - but what does that mean? Does that mean none of them work or that some of them do and some don't? If the latter, which ones?

Comment: @BrianThompson for sortId = 2 and 3 worked , but when I added the ordeyBy for sortId=1,2,3 it did not sort them

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
$query->whereHas('raffles',function($q2) {
    $q2->where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('sold_ticket', 'asc');
});
```

should be

```
$query->whereHas('raffles',function($q2) {
    $q2->where('active', 1);
})
->orderBy('sold_ticket', 'asc');
```

---

Maybe if you rewrote the query using the `when()` method?

```php
$products = Product::with('raffles')
    ->whereHas('categories',function ($q2) use ($categoryId) {
        $q2->where('category_id', $categoryId);
    })
    ->when($sortId == 1, function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('id');
    })
    ->when($sortId == 2, function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('raffles', function ($q2) {
                $q2->where('active', 1);
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    })
    ->when($sortId == 3, function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('raffles', function ($q2) {
                $q2->where('active', 1);
            })
            // sort the relationship column
            ->with([
                'raffles' => function ($q2) {
                    $q2->orderBy('sold_ticket', 'asc');
                }
            ]);
    })
   ->paginate(10);
```

This should work if `$sortId` is either `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'`. If `$sortId` is
a string like `'1,2,3'` or an array, you need to do things a bit differently.

`$sortId = explode(',' $sortId); // ['1', '2', '3']`

and in the conditions, instead of `$sortId == 1`, do `in_array('1', $sortId)`

Comment: It returns same result , and my problem is for 3 sortId s

Comment: I rewrote your query using `when()`. Does it still have the same problems?

Comment: thanks alot for sortId 1 and 2 it works , but for 3 does not work, sold_ticket is the column of raffles table . I updated it like this but it again does not work:    ->when($sortId == 3, function ($query) {
                    $query->whereHas('raffles', function ($q2) {
                        $q2->where('active', 1)
                            ->orderBy('sold_ticket', 'desc');
                    });

Comment: `orderBy` inside `whereHas` does nothing. `whereHas` compiles to an `EXISTS` query, so it does not care about ordering. To order the relationship, you have to do it inside the `with` closure.

Comment: so what is your advice?

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer. Try to see if it works

Comment: Thanks for your help , but I have same problem , orderBy does nothing

Comment: Mmm... Then the last option is to join with the raffles table. That way sold_ticket will be a column you can order by.

Comment: if with eloquent is impossible , I should join them :(((